# I need to insert code to an Elementor Pro button that changes its background color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I have 13 buttons aligned, whe the user selects one, It must change its background color and remains the same when the user returns from the form that the click event displayed, so the same must be for the same ones...

I tested in many ways with no success, I need help, please

Comment: Are the elements really buttons, or are they `input[type="radio"]`, styled to look like buttons? Can you please post the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, when a button is clicked, you want a button to change color when its clicked? If so, this answer can be found through html and some javascript:
You can use JavaScript to handle the button clicks and manage the state of the selected buttons. You can store the selected buttons in the browser's localStorage so that their state is preserved even if the user navigates away and returns. The handleButtonClick function toggles the 'selected' class on the button and updates the localStorage. When the page loads, it checks the localStorage to set the initial state of the buttons. The selected buttons will keep their state even if the user goes away and returns to the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        .button {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .selected {
            background-color: lightblue; /* Change this to your desired background color */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <button class="button" id="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button" id="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button" id="button3">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button" id="button4">Button 4</button>
    <button class="button" id="button5">Button 5</button>
    <button class="button" id="button6">Button 6</button>
    <button class="button" id="button7">Button 7</button>
    <button class="button" id="button8">Button 8</button>
    <button class="button" id="button9">Button 9</button>
    <button class="button" id="button10">Button 10</button>
    <button class="button" id="button11">Button 11</button>
    <button class="button" id="button12">Button 12</button>
    <button class="button" id="button13">Button 13</button>

    <script>
        // Simple object to mimic localStorage
        const mockLocalStorage = {};

        // Function to handle button clicks
        function handleButtonClick(buttonId) {
            const button = document.getElementById(buttonId);

            // Toggle the background color
            if (button.classList.contains('selected')) {
                button.classList.remove('selected');
                // Remove from mockLocalStorage when deselected
                delete mockLocalStorage[buttonId];
            } else {
                button.classList.add('selected');
                // Save to mockLocalStorage when selected
                mockLocalStorage[buttonId] = 'selected';
            }
        }

        // Function to set initial button states
        function setInitialButtonStates() {
            const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
            buttons.forEach(button => {
                // Check mockLocalStorage to set the initial state
                if (mockLocalStorage[button.id] === 'selected') {
                    button.classList.add('selected');
                }
            });
        }

        // Add click event listeners to the buttons
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
        buttons.forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener('click', () => {
                handleButtonClick(button.id);
            });
        });

        // Set initial button states when the page loads
        setInitialButtonStates();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```